# Cartesian extremities of a 3d segment

Tags: trigonometry, quaternions

I have a segment in 3d space and I want to calculate its extremities. I know the cartesian coordinates (x,y,z) of the segment's middle point, the segment's length L and the segment's orientation using quaternions (qx,qy,qz,qw)...so my question is how to get both cartesian extremities of the segment?
Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. The explain my situation, I am working with haptics devices connected with a stylus (a simple rod). I am calculating the middle of the stylus and its orientation according to a 3d frame (+y is right, +z is up and x is towards) in order to send thoses data to a robotic arm. Then I'd like to create a simple position controller to make the movement smoother, so I acquire the arm's end effector position/orientation that correspond to the middle of the stylus and send it back to the controller.

Comment: As I need to control both haptics separately so I need to calculate both stylus extremities . Thanks

Comment: Your orientation is given by a pure imaginary quaternion with $q_x=0$?

Comment: no, but my stylus have only 5 degrees of freedom, so in terme of euler angles, there is no roll.